# Measure words for disrespect

Tags: measure-word

I know certain measure words convey respect, for example:

> 一位客人

Is there something similar I could use to emphatically disrespect someone, as in:

> 他是一?饭桶

Or is just using `个` disrespectful enough?

Comment: [Measure words](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Measure_word) convey a unit of measurement. That's about it.

Comment: @QuestionOverflow: Yeah, but the words can still be tinted. 个 and 位 can measure a person, but one of those measuring sticks is more respectful.

Comment: "饭桶" is a disrespectful word, and to measure any type of "桶(Bucket)", one never use "位". If your focus is on "measure word", you could use another example like: why "他是一位作家" sounds more respectful than "他是一个作家".

Comment: @ash, "他是一个正人君子" doesn't convey less respect than "他是一位正人君子". Also most people would say "他是一个好丈夫" instead of "他是一位好丈夫". Measure words are neutral words.

Comment: I understand now. Although some measure words are typically paired with respectful nouns, the measure words themselves are only respectful by association and not because of inherent meaning.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

### General answer to disrespectful measure words

I can't recall any special disrespectful measure words in Chinese. Such disrespectful phrases are just expressed with simple measure words according to the noun. Like

> 他是
>
> - 一个笨蛋 [**offensive level: 1**]
> - 一个饭桶 [**offensive level: 2**]
> - 一个贱人 [**offensive level: 4**]
> - 一个傻逼 [**offensive level: 5**, with profanity word `屄/逼(cunt)`]
> - 一个二逼 [**offensive level: 5**, with profanity word `屄/逼(cunt)`]

or

> - 一坨屎 [**offensive level: 3**]
> - 一只(个)禽兽 [**offensive level: 2**]
> - 一条走狗 [**offensive level: 2**]

Note that the offensive level is my personal feeling: 1 is the lowest and 5 is the highest. You'd better not use `offensive level >= 3` words when speaking to somebody face to face, or, you'd better be ready for a fight :)

### Metaphor of measure words

A few Chinese people use measure words `只/坨` to show **emphatic disrespect with metaphor**.

> 他是一只小人。 (the measure word implies he is even not a human.)

But it is rarely heard in daily life. Interestingly, the official editorial often use

> 一 小撮 不明真相的群众
>
> 一 小撮 犯罪分子

to describe some kind of people are ***really few*** with a derogatory sense. It's a metaphor too, implying that kind of people are just like ***a small pinch of dust***.

### Common ways to emphasize your expression

To emphasize the expression, you can omit the numeral

> 他是个饭桶。 He is a scalawag.

Or you can also use `就是`, `真是`

> 他就是个饭桶。 He is exactly a scalawag.
>
> 他真是个饭桶。 He is really a scalawag.

And for shouting, omit the verb `是`

> 他个饭桶。
>
> 你个傻逼。

Comment: Concerning the readers of this website are language learners, it's important to point out that 饭桶/笨蛋 are rude language while 傻逼/二逼 are profanity words. The latter ones are much more harsh than the former ones, although they're used quite extensively.

Comment: @NS.X. Good advice.

Answer (score 2):

Hong Kong Cantonese uses the expression

```
(一  ) 條       友/友仔
(jat1) tiu4    jau5/jau5zai2
one    long:MW friend
```

as a contemptuous way of referring to a person. While 個 can be used instead, the measure word 條 suggests something long, slippery and unpleasant.